# How to update dashboard data with google sheet manually?

Tags: tableau-api

In tableau public when dashboard with google sheet published then tableau update data everyday or we can update manually shown in below image

[image]

but how to update manually using tableau api in embedded web?

i have already tried

```
 setInterval(function () {viz.refreshDataAsync() }, 3000);
```

[you can find the tableau api here](https://community.tableau.com/thread/158622)

Answer (score -1):

{edit: removing my answer of adding ?:refresh=yes to URl, that doesn't work in this case.}

Tableau public creates a extract of the data in google sheet, you would need to refresh that for viz.refreshDataAsync() to work.

I don't think tableau has exposed any javascript or REST API of refreshing the extract on Tableau public.

There are 2 (crappy!) options I see open:

1. Open the workbook in Tableau desktop client, refresh data source manually. Now republish the workbook.
2. Depend on Tableau to refresh the data. You can choose 'Keep my data in sync with Google sheet. Embed my Google sheet credentials' option while publishing to Tableau Public. Tableau will (hopefully!) refresh the extract once every day. See the image below.[image: Refresh option while publishing]

Comment: This will only refresh view. Updated data set from google sheet will not update in tableau dashboard

Comment: Mehul is right. I tried this out and tableau public did not refresh the data from google sheets. This seems to be happening because its using an extract of the google sheet data. ":refresh=yes"  will not work in this case. It will only work with 'live' datasources .